# Selecting distinct rows on all but one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to fetch distinct values of a table, which has an auto-incremented id field. I need the id to identify, but I don't care which id when all values are the same except the id.

I came up with the following, which seems to work. Is there a better way to do this though?

```
SELECT id, date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is 
FROM t
GROUP BY date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is
```

Another concern is, would this always return the same ids if the query is executed more than once?

EDIT:

Sample db:

```
id date_f date_t num_n num_d mn is
1   10      10      10  10   10 10
2   10      10      10  10   10 10
3   10      10      10  10   10 10
```

I want to store all of the columns of **one** row out of these. I don't care if the id is 1, 2 or 3 as long as it's the same the next time I execute the query (without adding/deleting any rows between). So far, two answers suggested using `min(id)` which seems like a good idea.

Comment: Can you please provide Sample Data and expected output?

Comment: @Uriil Okay, I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using the id in the result set at all, then the answer above will do the job.  If you need at least one Id in the result set for any purpose, then you should alter your statement slightly:

```
SELECT min(id), date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is 
FROM t
GROUP BY date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is
```

which will return the first Id that matches the distinct set (or use (Max) if you want the last - this will likely change over time though as data is added to the table.

Comment: Ok, this seems like a good idea. So if not using min or max on the id, it would be possible, that running the query twice wouldn't yield the same results?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how with having the Id in the select statement would work at all - it certainly would be unpredictable.  Using a min clause around the id (where id is an identity column) would generally return the same id for each set assuming the data isn't migrated and the id's reset within the table (call that bad practise data migration!). If you leave the id out altogether as suggested earlier, you'll definately get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically right - I would add that if you want the id (identity) then you need to add an aggregate such as -

```
SELECT min(id), date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is 
FROM t
GROUP BY date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is
```

this will make sure that you get the first/same one each time (unless of course it is deleted)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT date_f, date_t, num_n, num_d, mn, is
FROM t

Comment: But I need to store the id field. If there are 3 rows which have the same value on these fields, I need to store one of them, along with the id field.